# Remove Copyright area from blog template

Tags: html, ajax, web, blogger

I hv downloaded template for bloger and i want to remove copyright area else change it to blog itself but unable to remove it anyone guide me to change it
Blog code

```
 <div class='copyright-area'>Created By <a href='https://propertypartner24x7.blogspot.com/' id='mycontent' rel='dofollow' style='display: inline-block!important; font-size: inherit!important; color: #ff00ba!important; visibility: visible!important;z-index:99!important; opacity: 1!important;position:relative!important;' title='Property Partner'>Property Partner</a> | Distributed By <a href='https://propertypartner24x7.blogspot.com/' rel='dofollow' style='color:#ff00ba;' target='_blank' title='Property Partner'>Property Partner</a>
    </div>
```

code is showing as below on developer mode

Blog

Expecting Copyright by my blog itself

Comment: You shouldn't remove copyright notices from other peoples work

Answer (score 0):

You could inject some Javascript into the page when it loads, which then targets the div's class and then removes it from the DOM.

Many ways to do this, the above being one of them.

Answer (score 0):

you can remove it with js or jquery->
jquery :

```
$(document).ready(function(){$('.copyright-area').remove();});
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).